# Need to express some numbers as percentages where the total of the numbers equals 1 not 100?

Tags: math, expression

I need to express some numbers (for example, 1300, 500, 900) as a percentage where the total would be 1 not 100.

There could 10 numbers and the could be in the range of 1 to 99,999, I guess.

I need to do some maths in my program to convert these numbers into the appropriate values.

I'm probably not explaining this well.

Don't worry about the code, but heres what I need.

```
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Orange"];
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.2 withName:@"Fandango"];
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Blue"];
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Cerulean"];
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.3 withName:@"Green"];
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Yellow"];
    [chart addSlicePortion:0.1 withName:@"Pink"];
```

I need to produce the number 0.1, 0.2 etc. Notice that they add up to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide each of the numbers by the total sum of all of the numbers. So,

```
1300 / (1300 + 500 + 900) = 0.48148148148148148148148148148148
500 / (1300 + 500 + 900) = 0.18518518518518518518518518518519
900 / (1300 + 500 + 900) = 0.33333333333333333333333333333333
```

Note that the sum of these numbers is

```
1300 / (1300 + 500 + 900) + 500 / (1300 + 500 + 900) + 900 / (1300 + 500 + 900) =
(1300 + 500 + 900) / (1300 + 500 + 900) =
1
```

You can also check this by adding the decimal expansions given.

Answer (score 2):

A normal percentage has a total of 1.  If you have 1300, 500, and 900, add them up and then divide each by the total.  1300/(1300+500+900) for example.  This will give you 0.48...

Comment: Erm, I need to express each as percentage, but with 0.whatever.

Comment: It doesn't matter what numbers you use, if you add them all up and then divide each by the total then the total will always be 1.